# C how to define many variable the each name add 1 for switch case using

Tags: c

my code below, because define test_X will so many, maybe from test_1 to test_100.
If variables have 100, how can I simplify the code.
I don't want to write 100 lines. And switch case will run 100 times from 1 to 100.
How can I coding smart? 
Thanks!

```
#define test_1          0x0001
#define test_2          0x0002
#define test_3          0x0003
#define test_4          0x0004
#define test_5          0x0005
#define test_6          0x0006
#define test_7          0x0007
#define test_8          0x0008
#define test_9          0x0009
#define test_10         0x000A
#define test_11         0x000B
#define test_12         0x000C
#define test_13         0x000D

  // address will be address++
switch(address)
{
case test_1:
    temp = 1;
    break;

case test_2:
    temp = 2;
    break;

case test_3:
    temp = 3;
    break;
case test_4:
    temp = 4;
    break;

case test_5:
    temp = 5;
    break;
  .........
```

`test_X` are constant.
My goal is

1. define `test_X` are constant value for `switch case`.
2. run `switch case` depend by `address`, `address` will from `1 to X` by `address++`.
3. different case has different `temp`. I got the `temp` value to do another code.

Comment: you could generate the lines with an other tool but not with only C code.

Comment: Use an array.... Perhaps an array of function pointers... Or write a program to generate the C code above...

Comment: What keeps you from using an array and/or a loop?

Comment: I recommend to explain a little more about your goal. This gives the impression of an XY problem.

Comment: test_1, test_2, .... are not variables. They represent numbers

Comment: The posted code can be replaced by `temp = address`. However, I think there is more to your question than that. Try to give a more detailed description.

Comment: As a first step, replace your defines with a "enum" serie.

Comment: Is this purely academical or do you have a real use case in mind?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you could just use arrays and a loop.

Since the `test_X` are constants, let's make a `const` array to hold them like

```
const int test[100]={0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0004, 0x0005};
```

I just have 5 entries, you add the rest.

Now if the value to be assigned to `temp` are not following any pattern, declare another array to hold them like

```
int tempVal[100]={11, 22, 33, 44, 55}; //add the rest of the entries
```

Now use a loop like

```
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
    if(address==test[i])
    {
        temp=tempVal[i];
        printf("\n%d is the one", temp);
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Another way is to use [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) and `enum`. I'm not sure but this is probably not a good way of doing this.

First create a macro `X_LIST` for the required number of entities like

```
#define X_LIST X(1, 0x0001, 1) X(2, 0x0002, 2) X(3, 0x0003, 3) X(4, 0x0004, 4)
```

where the parameters are the number of the `test_X` variable (eg: 10 means `test_10`), value of the `test_X` variable and value to be assigned to `temp` respectively.

Now create another macro `X()` (the name can be any name. It needn't be `X` just because it's called X-macro) like

```
#define X(num, val, tempVal) test_##num=val,
```

This is the first version of `X()` that we use. This `X()` is for declaring the `test_X`.

Here, `test_X` are used as `enum` elements instead of macros.

Now let's make use of `X()` like

```
enum { X_LIST };
```

After pre-processing, this single line will expand to

```
enum { test_1=0x0001, test_2=0x0002, test_3=0x0003, test_4=0x0004, };
```

here, only 4 elements are specified, create more as per your needs.

The comma at the end is not a problem.

Now we undefine `X()` like

```
#undef X
```

and make the second version of `X()` like

```
#define X(num, val, tempVal) \
           case test_##num: \
       temp = tempVal; \
       break;
```

Then comes the `switch` statement

```
switch(address)
{
    X_LIST
}
```

And finally undefine `X()`

```
#undef X
```

That's it.

For the 4 elements, the C pre-processor would expand this to something like

```
 switch(address)
 {
  case test_1: temp = 1; 
               break; 
  case test_2: temp = 2;
               break;
  case test_3: temp = 3;
               break; 
  case test_4: temp = 4;
               break;
 }
```